# is it possible to define a dynamic shape for dtype?

Tags: python, numpy, shapes, dtype

say I define the following data type

dt = [('s', 'f4'), ('t', 'f4', (3,))]

and my matrix
a = np.empty((4,), dtype=dt)

This creates an array of the shape (4,). For a given element of array a, the field 't' has a fixed shape (e.g. a[0]['t'].shape of (3,) ). Now I was wondering if I can give the 't' a dynamic shape and append data series of different size into it?

theoretically something like this
a[0]['t'].append([4,6,9,10])
a[1]['t'].append([2,6,8])
etc

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: No.  that `(3,)` has to be common to all records.  That `dt` defines an array element size (`np.dtype(dt).itemsize`).  In an array all elements have the same size.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.